# Closing the popup window on a button click in the partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I am loading a partial view in a popup using the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //define config object
    var dialogOpts = {
        title: "Mypopup",
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 700,
        open: function () {
            //display correct dialog content
            $("#Mydiv").load("MyAction");
        }
    };
    $("#Mydiv").dialog(dialogOpts);    //end dialog

    $("#MyButton").click(
    function () {
        $("#Mydiv").dialog("open");
        return false;
    }
);

});
```

the action MyAction loads a partial view say "Myview" successfully, "Myview" contains a close button and on the click of this button I want to close the popup, How can I do this? I tried following code but this does not work.

```
$('#Close').click(
        function () {
            $(this).parent("close");
            return false;
        });
```

Can you please help?

Here is my html for the partial view.

```
@Code 
    Using (Html.BeginForm())
        @<div id="master">
        <img alt ="" src ="../../Images/Question.gif" height ="50" width ="50" />@Html.DisplayFor(Function(model) model.ConfirmationMessage) @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.Key )<br /><br />
        <div><input id="Yes" type="submit"  class ="btn" name="button" value="Yes" /><input id="No" type="submit"  class ="btn" name="button" value="No"  /></div>      
        </div>
    End Using
End Code
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#No").live("click", function(){ $("#MyDiv").dialog("close"); }); </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
$("#MyDiv").dialog("close")
```

or add the close buttons in the initialization of it

```
$( "#MyDiv" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: $("#MyDiv").dialog("close") is not working and I dont want to put the buttons in the initialization as the button is a part of the partial view rendered in this dialog

Answer (score 0):

I think i see it now.  That button is loaded dynamically so

```
$("#MyButton").live("click", function(){ $("#MyDiv").dialog("close"); });
```

Comment: can some one help on this please

Comment: Can you try in your javascript inside the function it should be #master not #MyDiv

Comment: Actually, maybe MyDiv is right if that is what is in your view that contains the partial

Comment: try moving your Javascript with the Live() to the main view and not in the partial

Comment: Hi Ryand, do you want me to write this javascript in the main view?<script type="text/javascript">     $("#No").live("click", function(){ $("#MyDiv").dialog("close"); }); </script>

Comment: Yes, i think it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

It will work we need to refer the following jQuery,jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css.

```
    $(function () {

        $("#dialog").dialog({

            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "jQuery Dialog",
            width: 500,
            height: 250

        });

        $("#btnShow").click(function () {

            $('#dialog').dialog('open');

        });         

    });

    function Close() {
      $('#dialog').dialog('close');

    };

</script>
```

for more details http://www.infinetsoft.com/Post/How-to-open-and-close-a-popup-in-asp-net-mvc-using-Jquery/99#.V0LlETV97cs